# How do I display erb code inside haml img src?

Tags: ruby, haml, erb, middleman

```
<% data.programs.client_name.each_with_index do |c, i| %>
   %article     
      .content 
         %header 
            .logo-wrap
               %img.client-logo{:src => "<%= data.programs.logo_url[i] %>", :alt => ""}/ 
        %div 
               %a{:href => ""} Program Title
               %p <%= c %>
        %p Some text description 
         %img.progam-photo{:src => "some_img_url", :alt => ""}/
<% end %>
```

I'm using Middleman local data functionality, so data here is getting from a yaml file. I just can't figure out how to output  <%= data.programs.logo_url[i] %> " on the  `img.client-logo src`.
So this process is being looped.

If i'll replace 
    %img.client-logo{:src => "<%= data.programs.logo_url[i] %>", :alt => ""}/ 
with a normal img tag i can output properly on the src.

This works:

```
<% data.programs.client_name.each_with_index do |c, i| %>       
%article        
        .content 
        %header 
        .logo-wrap                  
            <img class="client-logo" src="<%= data.programs.logo_url[i] %>" />      
    %div 
        %a{:href => ""} Program Title
        %p <%= c %>
    %p <%= data.programs.program_description[i] %>
    <img class="program-photo" src="<%= data.programs.img_url[i] %>" />     
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
%img.client-logo{:src => data.programs.logo_url[i], :alt => ""}/
```

possible caveats:

- data.programs.client_name is an array?
- is your code properly idented?
- if you replace the `%img` tag with `= data.programs.logo_url[i]` you have the link?

There is nothing wrong with the haml tag. This proves it:

```
[fotanus@thing ~]$ cat a.haml 
- a = []
- a << 'image/path'
%img{:src => a[0]}

[fotanus@thing ~]$ haml a.haml 
<img src='image/path' />
```

Comment: undefined local variable or method `i'

Comment: @clydealegro sorry, I don't understood your question so. What is the output you expects in HTML? What is the content of data.programs.logo_url? how is `i` not defined if there is used as index in the top loop?

Comment: <%= data.programs.logo_url[i] %> should output a url string. it works if it is like this <img src="<%= data.programs.logo_url[i] %>">, i just don't understand why it does not work in the haml format

Comment: `<img src="<%= data.programs.logo_url[i] %>">` should be equivalent of `%img{:src => data.programs.logo_url[i]}` and `= image_tag data.programs.logo_url[i]`. Edited the answer with possible caveats.

Comment: if it is working with this format <img src="<%= data.programs.logo_url[i] %>"> so i don't think there is a problem in retrieving the variable i. is there some interpolation i need to do if it is with the haml format?

Comment: @clydealegro edited my answer with a prove that this is not a haml tag problem

Comment: data.programs.client_name is an array. I think my code is properly indented per haml structure. i am getting i is not defined when i changed %img to = data.programs.logo_url[i]